# How to know if any app is accessing internal file in android

Tags: android, file

Is there any way to find out or store which app is accessing an internal file??

I want to develop an android app which will store the information about all the app which will access the internal files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to find out or store which app is accessing an internal file?

Fortunately no, except perhaps on rooted devices. You have no right to know what other apps are doing with regards to internal storage, any more than they have the right to know what you are doing with internal storage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but how we can do that on rooted device?

Comment: Have any one idea how to record the file system call.